# Standard Library http package logs to stdout by default, can I disable this?

Tags: http, logging, go

When using the built-in http module in Go, I notice that `http.ListenAndServe()` will make logging calls to `stdout` by default.  The main thing showing up in my terminal is:

```
http: TLS handshake error from x.x.x.x:x: tls: client offered an unsupported, maximum protocol version of 301.
```

Now I understand what this error is and what causes it, but the fact of the matter is, *I don't particularly care*.

How can I stop the http package (or `ListenAndServe()`, whatever) from logging to stdout by default?  It's clogging up my pretty console.  I'm 95% certain that I'm not the one logging the messages as all of the logs I have setup have "INFO", "WARNING" etc prefixes on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't log to stdout, it logs to the http server's `ErrorLog` if it's set, and to the standard logger (the one used by the non-method functions in [log](https://golang.org/pkg/log/)) otherwise. If you have a logger already, construct a `http.Server` with that logger as its `ErrorLog` and call `ListenAndServe` on that. Otherwise use `log.SetOutput` to change the destination of the standard log.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something straight forward but I was finding it rather difficult to google search an answer for this.